# Determining the number of days to reach significance

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, sample-size, statistical-power, sequential-analysis

Apologies for what I think will be a simple question - it has been some years since I've take statistics.

I run a business and we are attempting to determine the number of days required to reach a statistical sig. result for an A/B test regarding advertising spend.  We plan to shut-off catalog spend entirely for a portion of regions while leaving it on for others and compare to see whether there is a sig. impact on our bottom line revenue.

What puzzles me is how to determine the number of days to run the test considering there are many different variables that ultimately impact revenue beyond just catalog advertising (e.g. other media, weather, etc).

My thoughts at how to approach are:

1. Run a regression of catalog spend on overall revenue and determine coefficient
2. Determine what 2 standard deviations away from mean of weekly revenue is
3. Multiply catalog coefficient * 2 SD of weekly sales to determine how much to spend to see a result at 90% sig
4. Divide step 3 by average daily spend to calculate number of days

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no guarantee of reaching significance but by applying sequential analysis you can predict when it is likely to happen.

Comment: Hello Michael - What would that entail?

Comment: You define a stopping boundary.  Your units of measure are days. You can update your prediction as time progresses.

Comment: To take @MichaelChernick 's comment a step further, one option is to apply a sequential probability ratio test (SPRT) as described in this wiki article. Of course, the test presumes that you have predetermined the thresholds of significance that you want to reach.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_probability_ratio_test

Answer (score 1):

The sample size needed to reach statistical significance with a given probability depends on the effect size, which you don't know (if you already knew it, there would be no need to conduct this experiment). What's more, if the null hypothesis is true, your probability of attaining significance will be $α$, regardless of the sample size.

To me it seems that the most straightforward way to approach this problem is not with significance tests but with confidence intervals. Begin your experiment and regularly calculate a confidence interval for the effect. Once the confidence interval is narrow enough for your tastes, cease the experiment.

Comment: This recommendation is invalid, because the repeated confidence intervals are strongly correlated.  You need to use theoretically appropriate *sequential sampling* procedures, as sketched in a comment by @MichaelChernick.

Comment: @whuber I agree that these confidence intervals would be correlated, but in what sense does that make the strategy invalid?

Comment: It implies the confidence levels have coverage that are far from what you think they might be.  Consequently you don't really know what "narrow enough" actually means, so you have no valid procedure for determining when to stop.

Comment: @whuber So what you're saying is that if you ran infinitely many experiments and used this strategy each time, producing a final "95%" interval each time, it need not be the case that 95% of the intervals capture the respective true value? I see, that makes sense, because your stopping rule depends on interval width, which in turn depends on the data. But what "sequential sampling" method could you use to fix this? The only link in the comments is to a hypothesis test.

Comment: That's right.  For a quick overview, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis.  Chernick's comments, although telegraphic, will then be clear: the "stopping boundary" is the set of rules used to determine when to stop the sampling; which part of the boundary is reached when sampling stops will determine the decision that is made (that is, reject the hypothesis, accept it, or make no definite conclusion).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, but I don't see anything related to CIs there.

Comment: You are using CIs to test a hypothesis, so please think in those terms.

Comment: @whuber I am? I thought I was using CIs to estimate how revenue differs between the two conditions.

Comment: Your algorithm consists of a procedure with a *stopping rule,* following which (it was implicit that) the user was to *made a decision.*  That's a sequential hypothesis test.

Comment: @whuber The decision you refer to, presumably, is to choose whether to use the manipulation in the future. This decision is distinct from the question of whether the two conditions are significantly different. By "hypothesis test", do you mean something other than a null-hypothesis signifiance test?